# How can I search all Columns and Update specific value SQLite

Tags: java, database, sqlite

I have a SQLite database with 44 Columns and 700 rows. I created a user interface with Java ( I have two textFields and a Button) to search all columns with a specific value in first textField and update it with another value in second textField.

The problem is I don't know which column has the entered value in first textField, that's why I cant use directly `"Update table_name SET column_name ..."` Statement.

What I tried is ;

```
"Select * FROM table_name WHERE '%" + TextField.getText() + "%';
```

But it didn't work.
Can you help me to build right query?

Comment: You have to search in each column separately. Or use [FTS](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html).

Comment: @CL. isn't it can be done using nested queries. inner query appending all the columns of each row (using `||` )and outer one checking for the text using wildcard on appended data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could look into FTS tables as CL mentioned but another way is to create an easier way to query every column. You would create a function to loop through every column to make its where clause and join them all together using OR. One way to automate this and save writing all 44 column names is to query the database for all the column names and use that later for the query.

```
public String columnsLike(String like, String... cols) {
    return columnsLike(like, Arrays.asList(cols));
}

public String columnsLike(String like, List<String> cols) {
    List<String> where = new ArrayList<>();
    for(String column : cols) {
        where.add(column+" LIKE '"+like+"'");
    }
    return where.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(" OR "));
}

public List<String> getColumns(String table) {
    ResultSet rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM "+table);
    ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
    List<String> columns = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 1; i < rsmd.getColumnCount(); ++i) { columns.add(rsmd.getColumnName(i)); }
    return columns;
}

String query = "SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE "+columnsLike('%'+textField.getText()+'%', "column1", "column2", "column3", "column4", "column5");
// Result:
// SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column1 LIKE '%hello%' OR column2 LIKE '%hello%' OR column3 LIKE '%hello%' OR column4 LIKE '%hello%' OR column5 LIKE '%hello%'

// However you could save time from writing out every column and load them once into an array. 
List<String> columns = getColumns("table_name");
// Then call columnsLike('%'+textField.getText()+'%', columns);
```

---

To go about updating the values in the row that matched the select query you will have to go through the ResultSet rows and check them again in order to update that specific column. However, since I do not know if all of your columns are Strings I am using `getObject()` instead of `getString()` but you can change that if all of your columns are strings. Also, without knowing the data, multiple columns could match so this will update as many matches as it finds.

```
public void updateColumns(String tableName, List<String> cols, ResultSet rs, String like, String newValue) {
    PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("UPDATE "+tableName+" SET "+column+" = ? WHERE "+column+" = ? ");
    while(rs.next()) {
        for(String column : cols) {
            String value;
            if((value = rs.getObject(column).toString()).matches(".*"+like+".*")) {
                ps.setString(1, newValue);
                ps.setString(2, value);
                ps.addBatch();
            }
        }
    }
    ps.executeBatch();
    ps.close();
    // rs.close();
}

// updateColumns("table_name", columns, resultSet, textField.getText(), textField2.getText());
```

Comment: Select query is working like a magic, thank you. Can you help to build also update statement? When I send your query to database It will give me like full row and I want to update that specific value with textField2.getText() value. Thank you very much for helping

Comment: I edited my answer to include updating any matches found from the ResultSet.

Comment: Thank you for editing your answer, It is working for first 10 columns (when I enter a value from first 10 columns it finds and updates)  but after 11. column ( when it didn't find at first 10 columns )  gives me NullPointerException. How can it possible? I tried " rs.setFetchSize(100); " but it didn't work too. Can you help me ? Thank you very very much.